# Error in scheduled quartz job, unable to create new native thread

Tags: multithreading, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

2015-10-22 14:24:57,939 | system |  | Worker-5 | INFO  | jacorb.orb.giop | ClientConnectionManager: created new ClientGIOPConnection to 11.63.32.49:40000

2015-10-22 14:24:57,941 | system |  | Worker-5 | ERROR | | Could not perform supervision cycle. Error in scheduled quartz job.
unable to create new native thread

Is it a leak in the quartz scheduler which I doubt it would be, if so what's going wrong? Application runs for sometime and then just goes out of memory with the above error? Any help to resolve this fast?

Comment: You should perform a thread-dump.

Comment: Thread dump result,
"ClientMessageReceptor0" - Thread t@450
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <1fbc247> (a java.lang.Object)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
 at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.waitUntilConnected(GIOPConnection.java:333)
 at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.getMessage(GIOPConnection.java:373)
 at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessagesLoop(GIOPConnection.java:538)
 at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessages(GIOPConnection.java:527)   Most of the threads are stuck in the same..

Comment: Using jacORB client timeout to close the connection and it happens in server side as well but still the threads are in waiting state. Is there something missed still??

Comment: I have spoken with the submitter and they are currently using JacORB 3.1 ; we need to verify whether this has been solved already in 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Didn't close the orb resource opened properly. Added the below piece of code to ensure the same and viola no more out of memory issue :)

```
if(null != orb)
        {
            orb.shutdown(true);
            orb = null;
        }
```

Thanks Nick for helping with the pointers to fix the problem.

**Note:** This thread helped me to find the issue as well - http://www.jacorb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=632